# Why tflearn DNN softmax regression model's prediction is changing when executed on two different machines?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, logistic-regression, text-classification, tflearn

## Updated

I am working on the text multi-label classification using TFlearn softmax regression. I have training data and labels as in the class of that text data.
There are some labels which have 40% similar data. But the model fails to predict the same label on the two different machine. The model has trained on same epoch and same batch size but why the prediction of the labels (which are 40% same) is changing on two different machines. while the accuracy shows same on both machine.

## machine configuration:

**System Processor:** Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7200U CPU © 2.50GI-Iz 2.70 Gliz

**Installed memory (RAM):** 8.00 GB (7.79 GB usable) System type 64-bit Operating System, x64-based processor

Does Model prediction accuracy depend upon the processing power and speed of both machines?

Comment: What CPU/GPU do you use on each machine ?

Comment: @ChristopheRoussy Here is my configuration for both machines, I am using cpu. https://i.imgur.com/2EzvJtX.jpg

Comment: Post the config as text inside your question, you need to provide more information otherwise few people can help

Comment: @ChristopheRoussy Ok thanks for informing. Please refer my updated question.

Comment: Also see: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56362/why-do-i-get-different-results-each-time-i-run-my-algorithm, there might be some randomness in the initial phase (i'm not an expert ...)

Comment: @ChristopheRoussy Thanks for a quick reply I will check and get back to you.